# Monty Hall paradox - randomly generated number different from the previous two

Tags: matlab, random, paradox

I am writing a script to prove Monty Hall paradox in MATLAB and I have a problem -
I do not know how to make MATLAB generated a random number between 1 and 3 that is different from the previous two.

Here is my script:

```
% This program demostrates the Monty Hall paradox.
% A_pick1 represents where person chooses to put the five-pound note
% B_pick1 represents which box person B  first identifies
% A_pick2 represents the box that person A opens up - it must be different
% than both A_pick1 and B_pick2

A_pick1 = round(3 * rand(1) + 0.5)
B_pick1 = round(3 * rand(1) + 0.5)
A_pick2 = round(3* rand(1) + 0.5);
while (A_pick2 == A_pick1 || A_pick2 == B_pick1)
   A_pick2 = rand(3 * rand(1) + 0.5) ~= (A_pick1 && B_pick1)
    break
end
```

I am not sure how to use the while loop properly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) and [`setxor`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/setxor.html)?

```
A_pick1 = randi(3);
B_pick1 = randi(3);

x = setxor(1:3,[A_pick1, B_pick1]);
A_pick2 = x(randi(numel(x)));
```

There are other alternatives if you have the statistic toolbox, but I believe this should do quite well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
A_pick1 = round(3.0 * rand(1.0) + 0.5)
```

this way you ensure to have double.
Maybe you want to initilize your random number generator `rng` like in `rng('shuffle');`

Answer (score 0):

```
while (A_pick2 == A_pick1 || A_pick2 == B_pick1)
   A_pick2 = rand(3 * rand(1) + 0.5);
end
```